# How to Fix "A Database Error Occurred" in Codeigniter for IF condition in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to **Codeigniter**, Having error in mysql while using **IF Statement**, 
Here is my Code

```
$this->db->select('A.city_id, A.`name` AS city_name, B.`name` AS state_name, C.`name` AS country_name, IF(`A.visible`,"Yes","No") AS active');
$this->db->from('abs_city AS A');
$this->db->join('abs_state AS B', 'A.state_id = B.state_id AND B.visible = 1 AND A.country_id = B.country_id ', 'inner');
$this->db->join('abs_countries AS C', 'A.country_id = C.country_id AND B.visible = 1 ', 'inner' );
#$this->db->where('A.visible = 1');
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Error in Browser 
[image]

While removing tag(`) following query runs in phpmyadmin

```
    SELECT
    `A`.`city_id`,
    `A`.`name` AS city_name,
    `B`.`name` AS state_name,
    `C`.`name` AS country_name,

IF (A.visible, "Yes", "No") AS active
FROM
    (`vbs_abs_city` AS A)
INNER JOIN `vbs_abs_state` AS B ON `A`.`state_id` = `B`.`state_id`
AND B.visible = 1
AND A.country_id = B.country_id
INNER JOIN `vbs_abs_countries` AS C ON `A`.`country_id` = `C`.`country_id`
AND B.visible = 1
```

Please help me solve this, Thanks on advance.

Comment: so remove ` it from your query in CI

Comment: It automatically added form CI

Comment: not automatically you added in your code `IF(`A.visible`,"Yes","No")`

Comment: I second Bhargav. Just remove the backticks from your `$this->db->select()` statement. They are right there in the code, it's not CI that's putting them there. Some will suggest passing a `false` second parameter to achieve the same, but it makes no sense to make the whole statement less secure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the select method with `FALSE as the last parameter`, like this

```
$this->db->select('A.city_id, A.`name` AS city_name, B.`name` AS state_name, C.`name` AS country_name, IF(`A.visible`,"Yes","No") AS active',false);
```

That will prevent CI to add the ` in your query

Comment: It's much more logical and secure to remove the backticks from the select statement altogether (it's not like CI put the there, they are right there in the code), instead of writing them and then pseudo-removing them by lifting the escaping that CI does for safety.

Answer (score 1):

try update your query to

```
$this->db->select('A.city_id, A.`name` AS city_name, B.`name` AS state_name, C.`name` AS country_name, IF(`A.visible`,"Yes","No") AS active',false);
$this->db->from('abs_city AS A');
$this->db->join('abs_state AS B', 'A.state_id = B.state_id AND B.visible = 1 AND A.country_id = B.country_id ', 'inner');
$this->db->join('abs_countries AS C', 'A.country_id = C.country_id AND B.visible = 1 ', 'inner' );
#$this->db->where('A.visible = 1');
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the `false` parameter to your SELECT statement (which is inherently insecure), try changing the statement to:

```
$this->db->select('A.city_id, A.`name` AS city_name, B.`name` AS state_name, C.`name` AS country_name, IF(A.visible,"Yes","No") AS active');
```

(just remove the backticks around `A.visible`)

This is a more secure version than adding the `FALSE` parameter. The latter will prevent the automatic escaping that query builder adds to the built statement, rendering the whole select statement less secure, which is not advisable